# How to check hosted content for fraud?

Tags: web-application, html, fraud, sub-domain

I am a developer at a company that makes landing page software. Users can register and build their own page and publish it. We will provide them a subdomain on our whitelabel domain: `test-link.whitelabel-domain.com`.

Some users use our software to build scam pages and the whole domain `*.white-label.com` gets blocked (by most popular browsers).

Is there an API, open source software or implementations to resolve these problems?

I know wix.com, Leadpages and Webflow by example also provide users with a subdomain on their domains, so this is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by *\*.white-label.com get's blocked*? Sounds like an issue with the browsers not your website.

Comment: is a example but I mean if user a on user-a.domain.com posts a campaign that is scam user b on user-b.domain.com also gets blocked because the whole domain.com gets blocked

Comment: Can you give an example domain where this occurs?

Comment: There will be no way to do this because you would have to define what is good content and what is bad.

Comment: There are bots / crawlers on the internet that will find these website's and report them. Also companies like Webflow offer the same solution as us but they do not have these issues.

Comment: You are trying to prevent the blacklisting of your entire domain by inspecting the content of your user's pages. That's not a direct connection there. What you might want to do is to determine how to be recognised differently from your subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Shared resources and blacklisting is a common problem in Cyber Sec. If a company blocks a malicious IP, it could be an ISP NAT for hundreds or thousands of people. Similar issue is happening here where your higher level domain is getting flagged by the fake pages using registered sub-domains.

Here is the thing, the false pages are ultimately your companies responsibility. If your company can monitor for scam pages and prevent them from going up in the first place, ultimately the domain blocks should go away. Many of these are on a 30 day cycle (although I can't say for sure, it's company based). Can you not just have a review of each new page every day? I'm not sure how many new landing pages are being created here. You could definitely script something to pull all of your DNS and run it through a URL checking tool and send you alerts if something flags. That would at least get you closer to being ahead of the curve.

Frankly, the websites should be blocking your domain as long as you are hosting malicious Phishing landing pages (or etc). That's what that mechanism is for; to protect people from exactly that.